# Inequality involving the min function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

I'm trying to prove the following inequality: 
$$
\left|y_{1}\land x_{1}-y_{2}\land x_{2}\right|\leq\left|y_{1}-y_{2}\right|+\left|x_{1}-x_{2}\right|,
$$
where $x\land y=\mbox{min}(x,y)$. By considering different cases
it seems to hold but I haven't been able to find a simple way of proving
it. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try using $\min\left ( x,y \right )=\frac{1}{2}\left ( x+y - \left | x-y \right | \right )$? From https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min(x,y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the four cases:

- $y_1<x_1$ and $y_2<x_2$
- $y_1<x_1$ and $y_2\geq x_2$
- $y_1\geq x_1$ and $y_2<x_2$
- $y_1\geq x_1$ and $y_2\geq x_2$

By symmetry, you only need to consider the first two cases.

- The first case is simple because the LHS is a term on the RHS.
- For the second case, either $y_1<x_2<y_2$ so that $|y_1-y_2|=|y_1-x_2|+|x_2-y_2|$ or $x_2<y_1<x_1$ so $|x_2-x_1|=|x_2-y_1|+|y_1-x_1|$.  In either case, we get that $|y_1-x_2|$ is less than or equal to a term on the RHS.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in my question I've done that. I was wondering if there is a more concise and elegant proof.

Comment: What type of "elegance" are you looking for?

Comment: This is pretty elegant! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an exotic, one-line-r based on $$\min\left ( x,y \right )=\frac{1}{2}\left ( x+y - \left | x-y \right | \right )$$

$$\left | \min\left ( x_1,y_1 \right ) - \min\left ( x_2,y_2 \right ) \right |=\left | \frac{1}{2}\left ( x_1+y_1-\left | x_1-y_1 \right | \right ) - \frac{1}{2}\left ( x_2+y_2-\left | x_2-y_2 \right | \right ) \right |=$$

$$=\left | \frac{1}{2}\left ( x_1-x_2 \right ) + \frac{1}{2}\left ( y_1-y_2 \right ) + \frac{1}{2}(\left | x_2-y_2 \right | - \left | x_1-y_1 \right |) \right | \leq$$ 
$$\leq \frac{1}{2}\left | x_1-x_2 \right | + \frac{1}{2}\left | y_1-y_2 \right | + \frac{1}{2}\left | \left | x_2-y_2 \right | - \left | x_1-y_1 \right | \right |\leq $$

$$\leq \frac{1}{2}\left | x_1-x_2 \right | + \frac{1}{2}\left | y_1-y_2 \right | + \frac{1}{2}\left | \left ( x_2-y_2 \right ) - \left ( x_1-y_1 \right ) \right |= $$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\left | x_1-x_2 \right | + \frac{1}{2}\left | y_1-y_2 \right | + \frac{1}{2}\left | \left ( x_2-x_1 \right ) + \left ( y_1-y_2 \right ) \right |\leq$$

$$\leq \frac{1}{2}\left | x_1-x_2 \right | + \frac{1}{2}\left | y_1-y_2 \right | + \frac{1}{2} \left | x_2-x_1 \right | + \frac{1}{2} \left | y_1-y_2 \right | = \left | x_1-x_2 \right | + \left | y_1-y_2 \right | $$

Comment: That's quite cute!

Answer (score 1):

*(Using the approach from [Is $|f(a) - f(b)| \leqslant |g(a) - g(b)| + |h(a) - h(b)|$? when $f = \max\{{g, h}\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695420/is-fa-fb-leqslant-ga-gb-ha-hb-when-f-max-g)):*

If $x_2 \le y_2$ then
$$
 y_{1}\land x_{1}-y_{2}\land x_{2} 
 \le x_1 - x_2 \le \lvert x_1 - x_2\rvert \le \max \{ \lvert x_1 - x_2 \rvert, \lvert y_1 - y_2 \rvert \}
$$
and the same is true if $x_2 \ge y_2$. By symmetry it follows that
$$
 \lvert y_{1}\land x_{1}-y_{2}\land x_{2} \rvert \le
  \max \{ \lvert y_1 - y_2 \rvert, \lvert x_1 - x_2 \rvert \}
$$
which is slightly stronger than the desired
$$
 \lvert y_{1}\land x_{1}-y_{2}\land x_{2} \rvert \le
   \lvert y_1 - y_2 \rvert +  \lvert x_1 - x_2 \rvert \quad .
$$